# Integration test with Spring, Kafka and Testcontainers (Best practices to manage the lifecycle and clean up topics )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, spring-kafka

I use `testcontainer` to do an integration test with `spring` and `kafka`.
At times (especially when I run tests with maven - for example with `install`) tests crash...

Note that different integration tests may use the same topics to send or read messages.

I saw in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061911/how-to-clear-topics-in-tests-with-spring-kafka) that it was a good idea to create topics for each integration test.

So I use Spring with the Admin client to delete and create topics. It works perfectly but **I wondered how to create a topic and avoid having an exception if it exists, the same with deletion?**

All this to avoid concurrency problems...

Because at times the deletion did not have time to be done before the creation that follows...

It’s really frustrating because the tests fail randomly without me really understanding the reason

Here’s what I’m using right now :

```
public void recreateTopic(String topic) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    try (Admin admin = Admin.create(properties)) {

        Collection<TopicListing> topicListings = listTopics(new ListTopicsOptions(), admin);

        boolean exists = topicListings.stream().map(TopicListing::name).anyMatch(topic::equals);
        if (exists) {
            deleteTopic(admin, List.of(topic), new DeleteTopicsOptions());
        }
        createTopic(topic, admin);
    }
}
```

More generally I also wonder **what would be the right strategy to adopt to avoid this kind of random error** ? *(At times it may also happen that an error occurs because the topic is empty at the time of reading the message when it should not be...)*

Comment: Why do you need to do this; it's much simpler to use unique topic names in each test.